# Individual column-width viewport vw

Tags: css, tailwind-css

My individual columns (the `panes`) need to have individual (its own width) `width` because I have an `onClick` event for each `pane` which triggers a smaller or bigger width of each `pane`. Like this: `${navbar ? "col-w-[5vw]" : "col-w-[20]"}`

So this:

```
grid-cols-[20vw_20vw_20vw_100vw]
```

I would need to re-write into something like:

```
<div className="grid h-screen grid-cols-4 overflow-x-scroll">
  <div className="col-w-[20vw] overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-scroll">PANE*1*Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div className="col-w-[20vw] overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-scroll">PANE*2*Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div className="col-w-[20vw] overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-scroll">PANE*3*Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div className="col-w-[100vw] overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-scroll">
    <main>*MAIN*Lorem ipsum</main>
  </div>
</div>
```

and needs to work the same as -->>

```
<div className="grid h-screen grid-cols-[20vw_20vw_20vw_100vw] overflow-x-scroll">
  <div className="overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-scroll bg-yellow-400 text-50xl">PANE*1*Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div className="overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-scroll bg-green-500 text-50xl">PANE*2*Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div className="overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-scroll bg-blue-300 text-50xl">PANE*3*Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div className="text-50xl">
    <main>*MAIN*Lorem ipsum</main>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, unfortunately, it does not. How to correctly re-write if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider using `width` on the panels alongside `min-content` column track sizings like:

```js
const { useState } = React;

function App() {
  const [is1Open, set1Open] = useState(true);
  const [is2Open, set2Open] = useState(true);
  const [is3Open, set3Open] = useState(true);
  return (
    <div className="grid h-screen grid-cols-[repeat(4,min-content)] overflow-x-scroll">
      <div className={`${is1Open ? 'w-[20vw]' : 'w-[5vw]'} overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-scroll`}>PANE*1*Lorem ipsum</div>
      <div className={`${is2Open ? 'w-[20vw]' : 'w-[5vw]'} overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-scroll`}>PANE*2*Lorem ipsum</div>
      <div className={`${is3Open ? 'w-[20vw]' : 'w-[5vw]'} overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-scroll`}>PANE*3*Lorem ipsum</div>
      <div className="w-[100vw] overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-scroll">
        <main>*MAIN*Lorem ipsum</main>
        <button onClick={() => set1Open(v => !v)} class="block">Pane 1 Toggle</button>
        <button onClick={() => set2Open(v => !v)} class="block">Pane 2 Toggle</button>
        <button onClick={() => set3Open(v => !v)} class="block">Pane 3 Toggle</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<App/>);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Otherwise, you could use `grid-template-columns` in the `style` attribute like:

```js
const { useState } = React;

function App() {
  const [is1Open, set1Open] = useState(true);
  const [is2Open, set2Open] = useState(true);
  const [is3Open, set3Open] = useState(true);
  return (
    <div
      className="grid h-screen overflow-x-scroll"
      style={{ gridTemplateColumns: `${is1Open ? '20vw' : '5vw'} ${is2Open ? '20vw' : '5vw'} ${is3Open ? '20vw' : '5vw'} 100vw` }}
    >
      <div className="overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-scroll">PANE*1*Lorem ipsum</div>
      <div className="overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-scroll">PANE*2*Lorem ipsum</div>
      <div className="overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-scroll">PANE*3*Lorem ipsum</div>
      <div className="w-[100vw] overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-scroll">
        <main>*MAIN*Lorem ipsum</main>
        <button onClick={() => set1Open(v => !v)} class="block">Pane 1 Toggle</button>
        <button onClick={() => set2Open(v => !v)} class="block">Pane 2 Toggle</button>
        <button onClick={() => set3Open(v => !v)} class="block">Pane 3 Toggle</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<App/>);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```